# Visual Studio 2019 Doesn't seem to see that I have .NET Core 3.1 Installed (with SDK)

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I just installed Visual Studio a few days ago and for some reason I can't create anything but a class.

When I go to create a new User Control the pop up window lets me do everything except for click the "Add" Button to close the window and create the control.

If I double-click the User Control selector to create automatically, it pops up an alert box that says I need to go to the installer to get the .NET Framework target libraries. But when I go to the project's properties I see that I am already targeting .NET Core 3.1 and the only other option I have to target is .NET Core 3.0.... I assume this is because I'm in a .NET Core WPF application but I have no idea why it won't let me create a new control. It won't let me create anything except for a new class.

What is going on here? How can I work around this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced your problem recently. most of the templates were not installed after installation.

something you have to do is Modify your installation.

open `Visual Studio Installer` and click on `Modify` then choose the `features`(.Net core,Asp.net, Desktop Application and etc) in order to re-install them.

**keep it in mind** that, if `installer` encounters any problem or missing `dll`. installation **instantly** will be completed that should not happen.
**keep** your eyes close to your `installer` process and make sure all packages are installed.

a successful installation **MUST** not have any warning otherwise there are packages not installed.

it's better to install packages one by one **NOT** totally. I mean if you want the `Asp.Net Core` feature then try to install it at first. then try to install another feature.
Actually, I was not able to install whole features in a single installation and I don't know why. **in short, don't heavy your installation**.

**If the problem still exists then:**

**1.** Close all open solutions

**2.** Run `InstallCleanup.exe`

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe

**3.** Remove all existing `Visual Studio` programs from `Control Panel -> program features`

**4.** Restart pc and re-install Visual Studio

**5.** Make sure you have connected to the network

**6.** Choose only one feature(Don't select all) to install + Visual Studio Editor

### vs bug

Extensions don't work properly in VS 2019 and make it hang. it's may happen because the Extensions have to be updated to be compatible with vs 2019 or it's vs bug.

Comment: I feel like I've done that and nothing went wrong... I saw no warnings or anything... Would you say I should just re-install completely?

Comment: I will try to do a repair

Comment: @a_here_and_now actually it took a day installing vs 2019 correctly. and i don't know where is your actual problem

Comment: @a_here_and_now , if u couldn't to fix your problem tell me to put complex walking through here to fix your problem .

Comment: I went to the install and selected repair. It then asked me to reboot and after reboot everything is working fine. Thank you for the assurance that a repair was at least necessary as a bare minimum

Comment: @a_here_and_now your welcome.hopefully your problem was not so sever.i had a day trouble installing features .

Comment: Actually, when I reinstalled resharper the word System all over my project had been showing up in red and the term user control was once again not recognized. Any idea what could be going on here? I'd really like to keep using resharper, but with this happening I opted to repair once again and be sure not to touch resharper this time around

Comment: I have no idea what is going on now. It seemed to be working, it lets me make a User Control now. But now it won't recognize Initialize Component even, or other basic stuff like RowDefinition.

Comment: @a_here_and_now i will post you soon .